# How to show scrollbars in onsen ui app list

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm using Onsen Ui to build a hybrid Phonegap app. There are lists on some pages with 100's of items. But, the scrollbars are not showing. Is there anyway to show native like scrollbars on the page?

**Here is the code I'm using:**

```
          <ons-row >
              <ons-col align="center" >
                <ons-list  class="scrollme" ng-scrollbar is-bar-shown="true">
                    <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels" ng-click="viewHotel(hotel);">
                        <div class="hotel-item">
                            <img preload-image ng-src="http://domain.com/{{hotel.thumbNailUrl}}" default-image="img/loader.gif" alt="Thumbnail" class="testimage">
                            <div class="gradient-overlay" style="text-align: center">
                                <div class="details">
                                    <h4>{{hotel.name}}</h4>
                                    <h4>{{hotel.rateCurrencyCode + " " + hotel.highRate}}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ons-list-item>
                    <ons-button type="cta" should-spin="{{isFetching}}" 
                        ng-show="moreResultsAvailable" ng-click="loadMore()" class="loadMore">More Results</ons-button>
                </ons-list> 
              </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
```

**Update**

I have tried this [ng-scrollbar](http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-scrollbar) , But it's not working. Scrollbar itself scrolls up when I scroll the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite native apps, Onsen UI doesn't have a scrollbar element yet (version 1.3.1), but there are good chances that it will be implemented in the near future.

Source: I'm an Onsen UI development team member

Comment: So, is there any alternative I can use for the time being?

Comment: I'm afraid that there is nothing at the moment, except trying to develop it by your own. Of course, it's not so simple.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. So, when is the next version of Onsen UI releasing?

Comment: Soon, there isn't a release date yet, but the scrollbar element will not be implemented in the next release.

Comment: Ok, I have tried using default scrollbars of browser, I thought I would customize it to look better on phone. But, not showing at all...
here is some sample code
<div style="max-height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll">
     <p>...</p>
<p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p><p>...</p>
    </div>

Answer (score 3):

The `onsenui.css` file bundled with Onsen UI is hiding the scrollbar using this code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

To enable the scrollbars, you only need to un-do this by overriding the functionality, for example by adding this code to your `index.html`:

```
<style>
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: block !important;
    width: 5px;
    height: 0px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
</style>
```

**WARNING**

While this approach seems to work in the particular flavour of app I put together (Android only). The fact the development team hid the scrollbar, and don't have a way to put it back on the screen yet (see other answer by @Andy), makes me think that there might be some unwanted side-effects to re-enabling the scrollbar at the CSS level, (Im thinking along the lines of problems with the [lazy-repeat](http://onsen.io/reference/ons-lazy-repeat.html) control or cross-platform differences in look and feel). In other words: use at your own risk.

Answer (score 0):

In latest release of onsen-ui, now `<ons-scroller>` is used to scrolling purpose, so you can add it in your hmtl like bellow

```
<ons-scroller style="height: 200px; width: 100%">
<ons-row >
  <ons-col align="center" >
    <ons-list  class="scrollme" ng-scrollbar is-bar-shown="true">
        <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-repeat="hotel in hotels" ng-click="viewHotel(hotel);">
            <div class="hotel-item">
                <img preload-image ng-src="http://domain.com/{{hotel.thumbNailUrl}}" default-image="img/loader.gif" alt="Thumbnail" class="testimage">
                <div class="gradient-overlay" style="text-align: center">
                    <div class="details">
                        <h4>{{hotel.name}}</h4>
                        <h4>{{hotel.rateCurrencyCode + " " + hotel.highRate}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-button type="cta" should-spin="{{isFetching}}" 
            ng-show="moreResultsAvailable" ng-click="loadMore()" class="loadMore">More Results</ons-button>
    </ons-list> 
  </ons-col>
</ons-row>
</ons-scroller>
```